# update the same value of parent column as child list values in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
data = {
             'IDs':  ['A1','A10','A11','A12','A13','A14','A17','A10','A68','A7','A68','A34','A6','A24','A20','A21','A34','A14','A20','A68'],
             'S_S' :['G001','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
             'St_s': ['Pa','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
             'SsFlag': ['Pr','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
            'org_id' :[32,10,11,12,11,12,17,10,68,7,68,34,6,24,20,21,34,14,20,68,],
            'flag': [[ '32','68','7'],['10', '68'],['11', '12', '34', '6'],['12','24'],['11','20','21','34'],['12','14','20'],['17','10','68'],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

       } 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

output of the original dataframe:

```
Out[713]: 
    IDs   S_S St_s SsFlag  org_id              flag
0    A1  G001   Pa     Pr      32       [32, 68, 7]
1   A10                        10          [10, 68]
2   A11                        11   [11, 12, 34, 6]
3   A12                        12          [12, 24]
4   A13                        11  [11, 20, 21, 34]
5   A14                        12      [12, 14, 20]
6   A17                        17      [17, 10, 68]
7   A10                        10                []
8   A68                        68                []
9    A7                         7                []
10  A68                        68                []
11  A34                        34                []
12   A6                         6                []
13  A24                        24                []
14  A20                        20                []
15  A21                        21                []
16  A34                        34                []
17  A14                        14                []
18  A20                        20                []
19  A68                        68                []
```

Required dataframe:

```
data = {
             'IDs':  ['A1','A10','A11','A12','A13','A14','A17','A10','A68','A7','A68','A34','A6','A24','A20','A21','A34','A14','A20','A68'],
             'S_S' :['G001','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
             'St_s': ['Pa','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
             'SsFlag': ['Pr','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',],
            'org_id' :[32,10,11,12,11,12,17,10,68,7,68,34,6,24,20,21,34,14,20,68,],
            'rel_id' : [32,10,11,11,11,12,17,17,32,32,10,11,11,12,11,11,11,12,12,17,],       
           'flag': [[ '32','68','7'],['10', '68'],['11', '12', '34', '6'],['12','24'],['11','20','21','34'],['12','14','20'],['17','10','68'],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
           'Processed_first' :['','','','yes','','','','','','','','yes','yes','','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes',] 
       } 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df

Out[679]: 
    IDs   S_S St_s SsFlag  org_id  rel_id              flag Processed_first
0    A1  G001   Pa     Pr      32      32       [32, 68, 7]                
1   A10                        10      10          [10, 68]                
2   A11                        11      11   [11, 12, 34, 6]                
3   A12                        12      11          [12, 24]             yes
4   A13                        11      11  [11, 20, 21, 34]                
5   A14                        12      12      [12, 14, 20]                
6   A17                        17      17      [17, 10, 68]                
7   A10                        10      17                []                
8   A68                        68      32                []                
9    A7                         7      32                []                
10  A68                        68      10                []                
11  A34                        34      11                []             yes
12   A6                         6      11                []             yes
13  A24                        24      12                []                
14  A20                        20      11                []             yes
15  A21                        21      11                []             yes
16  A34                        34      11                []             yes
17  A14                        14      12                []             yes
18  A20                        20      12                []             yes
19  A68                        68      17                []             yes
```

I need a column to have an updated id depending upon the parent(org_id) and the childs(rel_id) column whose child list is there in flag column, also added processed_first for reference to explain the logic as the alerts are processed first, hence need not process that column.

for each element in the flag_list update the rel_id column, for the first time it gets the self-id same as org_id, the second element the related org_id column with the  should be updated by  parent_id, in rel_id column, for example in  first row 32 get 32 first as id, the second element 68 appears at the bottom 8th row hence gets an ID as 32 since 32 is its parent. Similarly, 2nd row 10 gets an id as 10 for the first time, and 68 appears again in 10th row and gets a related id as 10, process_firs indicates the alert is processed.

Comment: I don't understand the 'process_first' column can you explain in different terms maybe give me examples when yes, and when not?

Comment: Thank you, for example row 1 has a self id 32 and a related  id [68, 7 ]  now  68 which appears in the org_id column against row A68(IDs) so I am identify 68 parent as  32. let me try make one more example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is one way to update rel_id:

```
df_map = df.set_index('org_id')['flag'].explode().rename_axis('rel_id').rename('org_id').reset_index()
df_map = df_map.set_index(['org_id', df_map.groupby('org_id').cumcount()]).reset_index().dropna()
df_map['org_id'] = df_map['org_id'].astype('int')

df.set_index(['org_id', df.groupby('org_id').cumcount()]).reset_index().merge(df_map)
```

Output:

```
    org_id  level_1  IDs   S_S St_s SsFlag              flag  rel_id
0       32        0   A1  G001   Pa     Pr       [32, 68, 7]      32
1       10        0  A10                            [10, 68]      10
2       11        0  A11                     [11, 12, 34, 6]      11
3       12        0  A12                            [12, 24]      11
4       11        1  A13                    [11, 20, 21, 34]      11
5       12        1  A14                        [12, 14, 20]      12
6       17        0  A17                        [17, 10, 68]      17
7       10        1  A10                                  []      17
8       68        0  A68                                  []      32
9        7        0   A7                                  []      32
10      68        1  A68                                  []      10
11      34        0  A34                                  []      11
12       6        0   A6                                  []      11
13      24        0  A24                                  []      12
14      20        0  A20                                  []      11
15      21        0  A21                                  []      11
16      34        1  A34                                  []      11
17      14        0  A14                                  []      12
18      20        1  A20                                  []      12
19      68        2  A68                                  []      17
```

Comment: I can n't believe my eyes, it was a charm reply, I will have to digest this slowly..you saved me.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham Great.  I don't unerstand the process_first logic, but I think this works for your rel_id column.  If you don't mind upvoting and accepting I would appreciate it.

Comment: when i tried on my original dataframe df.set_index(['org_id', df.groupby('org_id').cumcount()]).reset_index().merge(df_map)  ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int32 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat;

Comment: That is why I use the astype(int) after dropping na. `df_map['org_id'] = df_map['org_id'].astype('int')`

Comment: Let me try again/check again

Comment: I had converted to str ahead in my code, thank you it works now.